# Privileges for installing executables with nsis

Tags: windows-7, administrator, installer, nsis

I think this question suits better superuser than stackoverflow.

I need to write an installer for some executables. The user might copy them wherever he wants but usually this is performed in C:\Program Files\MyProgram

If there's visual studio installed I also need to copy something to system32 (and that requires admin rights I suppose).

Does that make sense to support normal users and admin users? I mean: if I need to install something I always need admin rights, is this correct?

Comment: You don't always need Administrator permissions to install a program, it entirely depends, on what the group policy is.

Comment: Group policy for what? For what the program does?

Comment: There is a group policy that handles if if an Administrator permission escalation is required. If that is not turned on, additionally, a program can or cannot require Administrator permissions to be installed.  Adding a file to System32 is trivial with the installer of your choice, it requires escalation in nearly all solutions, but every single solution I have tried provide a simople and straight forward way of moving a file into the System32 folder ( although thats actually incorrect behavior ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a question about NSIS, take a look at [RequestExectutionLevel](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/RequestExecutionLevel.md) and the [UAC plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in). *Program Files/Program Files (x86)* and the *Windows* folders both require admin rights.